# How can I open an app, take a screenshot and send it to my PC automatically with a Nexus 7?

Tags: windows, android

So I have a Nexus 7 and ultimately what I want to do is have it open an app and let my computer see what the app sees.  I think the best way would be to either screenshot it or somehow mirror my Nexus 7 onto my PC [if that's even possible] -- this needs to be completely automated as well, however I can write some kind of small script for my PC if the mirroring option is possible.

Comment: And I assume creating screen capture software which emails the capture as a background task on your phone is not an option?

Comment: @DaveRook - There are apps that run in the background and take screenshots at a regular interval?  Am I correct in that is what you're suggesting?  Quickly trying to google this to find more details but do you have a name of an app that would do something similar?

Comment: I guess you would have to write something. As a whole, this would possibly annoy people and be very intrusive! What I meant was I've built apps and (for example) when the app crashes it emails me a screen capture so I can see where the error occurred and what was going on!

Comment: I think you may need to give away a little more about your project if I can answer any more thoroughly or accurately?

Comment: @DaveRook - I need to take a screenshot of an authenticator app.  Google "2 tier authentication" -- it is essentially an RSA keyfob in an app.  Sounds sketchier than it actually is, unfortunately I don't want to go deep into details beyond that.

Comment: OK - this gives me enough to kinda guess what it is you want to do - if the keyfob is your app, then you can trigger the screen shot at any time, if authentication comes from a 'barcode' approach then again, since it's your application which will read it you can trigger it

Comment: @DaveRook - Yes I think you understand.  Essentially I want my computer to automatically login to a service [happens to be a video game but could be anything] and that service requires you to use a keyfob/authenticator.  My thought was the easiest way to do this would be to somehow hook a tablet/smartphone up to my computer and somehow make them talk.

Comment: IMO, you would be better to do this via the device as a separate app all together: When your PC app wants authentication, it checks a server to see if it is granted, and polls every 10 seconds until it is. You can then use this time to take a photo of a keyfob/authentication interface with your phone via your mobile phone app - this then OCR the words/numbers of the keyfob, sends it to the server, confirms it is OK (or returns to the phone it is not) and the next poll of the PC app will allow log in. You will need login details on both phone / PC to match to allow syncing of accounts!

Answer (score 1):

If you enable USB debugging on your device and install Android SDK on your PC you can do this by a script:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

The package name can be retrieved by listing all installed packages:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

This starts the app specified by package name and activity name.
The ActivityName is a bit harder to get. It is written in the Manifest ambedded in the App APK file. Therefore you could pull the APK file from the device and read the manifest via `aapt` or you get the AndroidManifest via [ManifestViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer).

Then create the screen shot and download it to the PC (works with Android 4.0 and higher):

```
adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png screenshot.png
```

Comment: How do I find the correct package and activity names?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks will investigate this a bit more over the weekend

Answer (score -1):

I just was looking for something similar as I seen Samsung tablet screen sharing with laptop that was connected to projector. This was done with [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) app on laptop and [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market.samsung), but this is at this moment only available to Samsung devices. (You can with their other apps remotely control pc or join meetig call, but that is about it).
Next app I'm playing with is [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnNhbmQuYWlyZHJvaWQiXQ..) but this has only limited access to files, multimedia. To be able to squeeze out more you will have to root your device and grant access. If I find something else more suitable for android device sharing to pc/laptop I will update this.